# No me permite actualizar repositorio de git

Tags: git, github, git-push, control-de-versiones

Llevo relativamente poco tiempo utilizando git, y en el trabajo creé un repositorio nuevo en mi cuenta de GitHub e hice push de unos archivos que me interesaba guardar.

Ahora, desde otro ordenador, me interesa hacer push de otros archivos en el mismo repositorio que creé en el trabajo y no me permite hacer esta acción.

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? ¿Qué puedo configurar para poder actualizar mi repositorio desde ordenador en el que inicialmente no haya subido los primeros cambios?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece ser que ya existe un repositorio enlazado con ese proyecto.

Comment: Probablemente tengas en uno de los directorios hijos otro `.git` el cual entiende que **ya habias creado un proyecto anteriormente** enlazado a ese directorio, buscalo y borralo entonces prueba de nuevo, hace poco me paso eso a mi

Comment: Efectivamente, tenia un .git en otro subdirectorio. Lo he borrado, he vuelto a hacer lo mismo y me aparece exactamente el mismo error. No será que he de configurar para poder hacer push a un respositorio que ya está creado? Piensa también que el directorio de origen desde donde inicialmente hice push, es totalmente distinto al directorio desde donde ahora, quiero hacer push.

Comment: Hola, en tu ordenador 2, hiciste pull previo a modificar los archivos? Lo que me parece que puede estar pasando es que se han desincronizado los repos (asumo que quiere trabajar sobre la misma rama). Podrias postear el resultado de `git log --decorate --oneline --all --graph`? y si compartes el repo de github podría indicarte mejor los pasos a seguir (claro, si es posible)

Comment: @gustavovelascoh el resultado es: * 64ea83b (HEAD -> master) subida directorio apuntes y mas

Comment: ese es el ultimo commit, fue ese el commit que hiciste desde el ordenador del trabajo?

Comment: No, éste es el commit, que si te fijas en la imagen, hago en éste último intento de hacer push al repositorio remoto inicializado desde el trabajo

Comment: Por lo que veo no has hecho cambios...  creo que lo qiue tienes es un repo local con un  directorio vacio. Lo que debes hacer es o `git pull origin master`  o usar un nuevo directorio para clonar el repo de github, fuera de este directorio ejecutando `git clone https://github.com/MNoventa/Directorios.git`

Comment: haz un clone del repositorio primero y luego hacer el push

Answer (score 2):

debes de realizar lo que te comenta en líneas amarillas.
Actualizas tu repositorio local ejecutando el comando "git pull" y enseguida intenta realizar nuevamente el git push.

Te dejo una documentación sobre el funcionamiento de [git pull](https://www.atlassian.com/es/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull#:%7E:text=El%20comando%20git%20pull%20se,local%20para%20reflejar%20ese%20contenido.&text=El%20comando%20git%20pull%20es,fetch%20seguido%20de%20git%20merge%20.)

En pocas palabras, debido a que realizaste cambios en tu repositorio remoto y después realizaste cambios en tu repositorio local, git te dice que debes primero actualizar tu local y después cargar tus cambios; como buena practica debemos de procurar actualizar nuestra local y después empezar a modificarla (esto como una buena practica).

Answer (score 1):

prueba `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master` para decirle a tu repositorio remoto que tu rama master del repositorio local coincide con la rama master del repositorio remoto.

Si eso no funciona te recomiendo que en lugar de inicializar el repositorio y actualizar las referencias intentes hacer `git clone url` y entonces remplazas los ficheros modificados en donde hayas clonado el repositorio y ya deberías tener enlazadas las referencias al haber descargado directamente el repositorio. También prueba con `git add -A` y a hacer el commit con `git commit -a -m "message"` para trackear todos los ficheros y añadirlos al commit

Comment: Todo esto lo hago después de lo que ya he hecho hasta ahora? Podrías especificarme los pasos?

Comment: En otra carpeta `git clone urlDeTuRepositorio` y entras en el directorio del proyecto con `cd nombredeproyecto`, seleccionas la rama `git checkout master`. Modificas los archivos que necesites o remplazas con los ficheros de tu antiguo proyecto que ya habías modificado y ejecutas `git add -A` `git commit -a -m "mensaje"` y `git push -u origin --all`

Answer (score 1):

Git es un sistema de repositorios distribuido. Hay un repositorio remoto ("origin" en github), y cuando haces `git clone`, haces una copia de ese repositorio en tu ordenador. Los *commit* son una secuencia de estados del repositorio que deben estar en sincronía entre el repositorio en github y las copias de los desarrolladores, o en tu caso, tu mismo en diferentes equipos.

En tu caso, creo que puedes solucionarlo con estos comandos.

```
git stash # Guarda el estado actual de los archivos
git pull origin master # sincroniza con los cambios en el remoto
git stash pop # Aplica los cambios guardados anteriormente
git add -A # Prepara los archivos para el commit
git commit -m "Nuevo commit en ordenador 2" # Crea el commit
git pull origin master # Sube el nuevo commit al remoto
```

---

El problema es que `git init` se usa para crear nuevos repositorios en tu equipo (repositorio local), que luego pueden ser subidos a un remoto. Esto pudo haber sido el caso en el ordenador del trabajo.

Cuando quieres trabajar en un repositorio existente (ordenador 2), usas el comando `git clone`, el cual realiza una copia del repositorio remoto y lo guarda como local.

En ese punto los 2 repositorios locales (trabajo y ord. 2) estarían en el mismo estado.

El proceso sería algo así:

**Ordenador Trabajo**

- **git init, git add, git commit:** Se crea el repo local en ord. trabajo y tendria el commit A
- **git remote add**: Asignas el repositorio remoto para sincronizar
- **git push**: El repo remoto ahora contiene el commit A

**Ordenador 2**

- **(ord. 2) git clone, [git checkout]:** El repo en ord. 2 tendria el commit A al copiar el repo remoto. Se usa checkout en caso de trabajar en otra rama diferente a la master
- **git add, git commit:** Se hacen modificaciones y se crea el commit B. En este punto la historia es (A->B)
- **git push**: El repo remoto ahora contiene el commit B, (A->B)

En tu caso al hacer `git init, git add, git commit` en ord 2, estas creando otro repositorio con un commit B (como unico e inicial commit), y aunque lo apuntes al remoto, no te permitira subir los cambios ya que hay inconsistencias en la historia del repo (commit B no existe)

Comment: Ok, entonces hago un clone del repositorio remoto y me aparece este error: $ git clone https://github.com/MNoventa/Directorios.git
fatal: destination path 'Directorios' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Además, ya habia borrado el .git de las anteriores pruebas

Comment: el error es que hay un directorio con el nombre "Directorios". intenta entonces `git clone github.com/MNoventa/Directorios.git directorios_ord2` o algo similar. Otra opcion es renombrar o  borrar el directorio `Directorios`.

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo git. Por ello, después de git clone github.com/MNoventa/Directorios.git directorios_ord2 (que no me escupe ningún error, así que bien), el git pull de qué deberia de ser? git pull https://github.com/MNoventa/Directorios.git? Luego add . (imagino), git commit -m "Nuevo commit en ordenador 2" (por ejemplo) y luego git push origin master?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta. No es `git pull`, es `git checkout` y es opcional. Después de clonar el repo remoto, puedes verificar que tienes el último commit usando `git log`